# Terraform Databricks Storage credential for an Access Connector with User Assigned managed identity

Tags: terraform, databricks, azure-databricks, terraform-provider-azure, terraform-provider-databricks

I have a databricks access connector, that I created for accessing external locations . The access connector created has a user defined managed identity (not a system assigned one).

Now when I try to create a storage credential in Terraform using that access connector, I get an error saying

```
cannot create storage credential: Azure Managed Identity Credential with Access Connector Id nameofcred  could not be found
```

Using this:

```
resource "databricks_storage_credential" "storage_credential" {
  name = "example_cred"
  azure_managed_identity {
    access_connector_id = <entered the resource id for the Access Connector for Azure Databricks>
  }
  comment = "Managed identity credential managed by TF"
}
```

And this is how my access connector looks like (configured with userAssigned Identity)

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "accessConnectors_ac_connector_rxample": {
            "defaultValue": "example_name",
            "type": "String"
        }
    },
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Databricks/accessConnectors",
            "apiVersion": "2023-05-01",
            "name": "[parameters('accessConnectors_ac_connector_example_name')]",
            "location": "northeurope",
            "identity": {
                "type": "UserAssigned",
                "userAssignedIdentities": {
                    "/subscriptions/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/resourceGroups/rg-example/providers/Microsoft.ManagedIdentity/userAssignedIdentities/userassignedminame": {}
                }
            },
            "properties": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the terraform resource link (Azure is the cloud provider): [here](https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/blob/master/docs/resources/storage_credential.md)

Is User Assigned managed identity not supported?

I also tried with `azure_service_principal` block with `directory_id` and `application_id`, but it keeps failing because `client_secret` is a required property, and since this is a user defined managed identity, I can't create secrets (it is just listed as an SPN aka enterprise application in Azure AD).

Is this not supported?

From the GUI it is supported:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I also tried with `azure_service_principal` block with `directory_id` and `application_id`, but it keeps failing because `client_secret` is a required property, and since this is a user defined managedidentity, I can't create secrets (it is just listed as an SPN aka enterprise application in Azure AD).

User Assigned Managed Identities are not supported in Terraform for creating storage credentials.

Storage credential represents an authentication and authorization mechanism for accessing data stored on your cloud tenant, using either an `Azure managed identity` or a `service principal`. follow the [Ms Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-external-locations-and-credentials#what-are-external-locations-and-storage-credentials) about Storage credential.

Alternatively, you can create storage credentials using a service principal by following the steps below.

Create a service principal in the Azure portal and provide it access to your storage account.

1. Create a client secret for the service principal and note down the `directory ID` , `application ID`  and `Client Secret` for the service principal.
2. Log into your storage account and assign the service principal the **Storage Blob Data Contributor** role. Follow the instructions in the [MS doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data-governance/unity-catalog/manage-external-locations-and-credentials#--create-a-storage-credential) about `Data bricks storage credentials` using service prinicipal

I created a `Databricks storage` credential using a service principal using `Terraform` code

```
   provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
    }
    databricks = {
      source = "databricks/databricks"
    }
  }
}

# Use Databricks CLI authentication.
provider "databricks" {
profile = "DEFAULT"
host    = "Databricks-URL"
}
resource "databricks_storage_credential" "storage_credential" {
  name = "databricks-storage"
  azure_service_principal {
    application_id   = ""
    directory_id     = ""
    client_secret   = ""
  }
  comment = "Service Principal credential managed by TF"
}
```

**Terraform Plan:**

[image]

**Terraform Apply:**

[image]

Comment: Hi Venkat, thanks for responding. My question was only w.r.t be able to use the user defined managed identity for the databricks access connector. I was not asking for the service principal method (only asking if that could somehow be used to define the user defined managed identity), because that needs extra overhead of maintaining and generating secrets. I have since then reverted to using a system defined managed identity for the access connector.

Comment: User-defined managed identity directly with an Azure Databricks access connector might not be [supported](https://i.imgur.com/5QceVvB.png). Using a system-defined managed identity for the access connector is a reasonable approach in this case.

Comment: It is supported from the UI within the Databricks workspace- just not in terraform.

Comment: the question here is about the Storage credential through terraform- refer to the question.

Comment: Added a screenshot from the GUI in the question.

Comment: Yes, In order to create storage credentials using Terraform below are only options: Service prinicipal and system-defined managed identity. 
Is posted solution is helpful?

Comment: If you edit your answer to only mention that user defined identity is not supported for Terraform (creating a storage credential using an access connector), I would accept it. right now, it has info, which is not relevant to the question. Also, user defined identity when creating an accessconnector is also supported- mentioned here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/templates/microsoft.databricks/2022-10-01-preview/accessconnectors?pivots=deployment-language-terraform

Comment: Hi @SaugatMukherjee, Updated Answer with same point.

Comment: UMI supported since release 1.25.0: https://github.com/databricks/terraform-provider-databricks/releases/tag/v1.25.0

Answer (score 2):

You should upgrade databrick provider to the lastest version and **managed_identity_id** into **azure_managed_identity** block.

Like this:

```
resource "databricks_storage_credential" "storage_credential" {
  name = "example_cred"
  azure_managed_identity {
    access_connector_id = <entered the resource id for the Access Connector for Azure Databricks>
    managed_identity_id = <resource id of Managed Identity>
  }
  comment = "Managed identity credential managed by TF"
}
```

Doc: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/databricks/databricks/latest/docs/resources/storage_credential

Comment: Cool- looks like they added it, in the latest release.